# Probability of a continuous random variable being inside a sphere in $\mathbb{R}^k$

Tags: probability

Let $X \in \mathbb{R}^k$ be a continuous random variable with density $f(x)$.

I want to know the probability that $||X - a|| \leq \epsilon$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}^k$ and $\epsilon>0$.

I found the formula:
$$Pr(||X - a|| \leq \epsilon) = \int_0^\epsilon r^{k-1} \left( \int_{\mathbb{S}_k} f(a + r \omega) \lambda_{\mathbb{S}_k} (d \omega) \right)dr, $$
where $\mathbb{S}_k = \{ \omega \in \mathbb{R}^k : ||\omega||=1 \}$ is the unit $k$ sphere, and $\lambda_{\mathbb{S}_k}$ is its surface measure.

I would like to know how this formula can be derived, or at least get some intuition on why it is valid.

Comment: It would be a Fubini's theorem application, wouldn't it? An integral over the ball of radius $\epsilon$ can be broken into the spherical slices with the surface measure.

Comment: As far as intuition goes, you can think of it as a higher dimensional analogue of integration with respect to polar coordinates.